# c# How to enforce uppercase in a specified colum of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to be able to set the CharacterCasing of a specified column to uppercase.

I can't find a solution anywhere that will convert characters to uppercase *as they are typed*.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 8):

You need to use EditingControlShowing event of the Datagridview to edit the contents of any cell in a column. Using this event you can fire the keypress event in a particular cell. In the keypress event you can enforce a rule which will automatically convert lowercase letters to uppercase.

Here are the steps to achieve this:

In the EditingControlShowing event see whether user is in the column in which you want to enforce this rule. Say your column is 2nd column in the grid

```
private void TestDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if(TestDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(1))
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress += Control_KeyPress; // Depending on your requirement you can register any key event for this.
    }
}

private static void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Write your logic to convert the letter to uppercase
}
```

If you want to set the `CharacterCasing` property of the textbox control in the column, then you can do it where `KeyPress` event registering is done in the above code, which is in the 'if' block of checking column index. In this case you can avoid KeyPress event.

That can be done in the following way:

```
if(e.Control is TextBox)
{
  ((TextBox) (e.Control)).CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
}
```

Comment: I think DataGridView should be replaced with the name of your grid in the if(DataGridView... statement.

Comment: Since I don't like to hard-code column indexes, I choose to refer to the 'Name' property of the column to see if it is the column i want.  Instead of if(DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(1)), use: if(myDGV.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name == "MyCol").  Probably less efficient, but much easier to maintain.

Comment: @shindigo: Agreed. DataGridView is a class name and I wont use in realtime, this is done here as I'm giving an example on how to do it. Yes, I never use such name in my projects, every grid will have its name as per usage. Anyway will change the name her as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently i really know, but if you could get access to the editing control of the column (which is a TextBox) you could probably set the [CharacterCasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.charactercasing.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

**Use EditingControlShowing event of the Datagridview to Edit the contents**

*After that Apply the Condition For Specific Column*

```
private void dgvGrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (dgvGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 || dgvGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
          {
           if (e.Control is TextBox)
              {
                ((TextBox)(e.Control)).CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
              }
          }
    }
```

*Happy Coding*